# Getting output from 'info' into the RStudio Viewer window

Tags: r, expss

Thought this would do it - but still goes to Console.

```
expss_output_viewer()
data(mtcars)
info(mtcars, max_levels = 5)
expss_output_default()
```

But it seems only table output is redirected by `expss_output_viewer()`
Package manual [Page 58] suggest one loads the file info into RStudio viewer.

How is this done?

Answer (score 0):

There is inaccuracy in the manual at this point. By viewer it means "data viewer" - tab which appears when you click data in the object browser or call `View` function:

```
data(mtcars)
View(info(mtcars, max_levels = 5))
```

Alternatively, you can view it as HTML by using `as.etable`:

```
expss_output_viewer()
data(mtcars)
as.etable(info(mtcars, max_levels = 5))
expss_output_default()
```